# How to display duplicate id value in tooltip in jquery?

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter, jquery-ui-tooltip

```
<script>
    var show_askpath_img_student_detailed = <?=json_encode($_SESSION['question_askpath_img'])?>;

    $.each(show_askpath_img_student_detailed, function(key, value) {
        $("#questionmark"+key).tooltip(
            {
                content : value['askpath'],
                show: { effect: "Fade", duration: 250 },
                hide: { effect: "Fade", duration: 150 },
                position: { my: "left bottom-50", at: "center top", collision: "flipfit" },
                classes: {"ui-tooltip": "ui-tooltip-asktext"}
            }
        );
    });
</script>
```

If there are 10 results on the first page
The tooltips for the ten are well displayed.

However, the tooltips for the results of the next page are not displayed.

I printed the array with `print_r` function to check the result, 
and confirmed that the first page, the second page, the third page ... 
all output the result well.

I think the id value is duplicated and the tooltip does not appear.

How do I get all the tooltips to display?

Comment: do you have a `session_start()` at the top of the script? I dont see it...

Comment: @Jeff I do not know what you're asking.

Comment: If that code runs once, when the page loads, then you've only called the `.tooltip()` function on elements that actually existed at that moment. If page two of the results is loaded via Ajax you'd need to call `.tooltip()` again after that.